# Can't access jQuery UI from inside a class function when loaded programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am loading jQuery and jQuery UI programmatically like this:

```
const jQuery_3_6_0 = document.createElement('jQuery_3_6_0');
jQuery_3_6_0.src = '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js';
jQuery_3_6_0.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQuery_3_6_0);

const jQuery_ui = document.createElement('jQuery_ui');
jQuery_ui.src = '/js/jquery-ui.min.js';
jQuery_ui.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQuery_ui);
```

then, I am declaring a class inside of the jQuery function:

```
(function($) {

    class Moo {
        constructor() {
            let classThis = this;
            window.$(document).on('click scroll keyup', function (e) {
                classThis.catchEvent(e);
            });
            this.debug.init();
        }

        debug = {
            init: function (content) {
                window.$("body").prepend(
                    "<div " +
                    "   style='position:absolute; padding:10px; background: #333; color: #FFF;'" +
                    "   id='debug'>" +
                    "</div>");
                this.setOutput(content);
                window.$("#debug").draggable();
            },
            setOutput: function (content) {
                window.$('#debug').text(content);
            }
        }
    }

    let cow= new Moo();

}(jQuery_3_6_0))
```

jQuery loads fine, but I can't make the new element draggable(). All I get back is:

`Uncaught TypeError: window.$(...).draggable is not a function`

**The Question**

How do I get my script to load jQuery UI and then get my class function to use draggable()?

Comment: Are you certain jQuery is loading fine as both `document.createElement('jQuery_3_6_0')` and `document.createElement('jQuery_ui')` are incorrect. You're trying to create `<jQuery_3_6_0 />` and `<jQuery_ui />` elements. These need to be `<script>` elements instead.

Comment: @rory yeah, jQuery is definitely working. I tested that first. I'm not sure why ui isn't though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan after testing, apparently jQuery was _never_ working. It was imported otherwise from my test script. I am adding the answer, because I just figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code above is that it wasn't waiting for each to load. Additionally, as Rory pointed out in the comment, my element was wrong.

Thus, I have updated my code as shown below and it now works!

```
let jQuery_3_6_0 = document.createElement('script');
jQuery_3_6_0.setAttribute('src', 'http://myurl.com/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js');
jQuery_3_6_0.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.head.appendChild(jQuery_3_6_0);

jQuery_3_6_0.onload = () => {

    let jQuery_ui = document.createElement('script');
    jQuery_ui.setAttribute('src', 'http://myurl.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
    jQuery_ui.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.head.appendChild(jQuery_ui);

    jQuery_ui.onload = () => {

        class Moo
        {
            //class stuff.... including element.draggable()
        }

        let cow = new Moo();
    }

}
```